# Sum time intervals using linq

Tags: c#

I have a problem; actually I am having workingHours in my database table in the format HH.mm and I want to sum all the working hours using LINQ can any 1 please tell how to do this.

In totalWeekHours I have all the working hours and I have replace HH.mm format in HH:mm but I don't know how to parse it in `timespan` and then `Sum()` using Linq.

please help.

```
var totalWeekHours = (from twh in db.MytimeMaster 
                      where ((twh.date >= lstsun && twh.date <= tilldate) 
                          && (twh.agentID == agentid)) 
                      select twh.totalworkinghours).ToList();

if (totalWeekHours.Count > 0) 
{
    List cnvrtToTimespanlist = new List(); 
    foreach(var list in totalWeekHours) 
    {
        cnvrtToTimespanlist.Add(list.ToString().Replace('.', ':')); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code more usefully... and why is your database data in text form anyway? Can you change that in any way? (For example, a numeric value of "working minutes" would be fine.)

Comment: "can any 1"...please. I understand English is not the first language for many folks on Stack Overflow, but that's no excuse for using text slang.

Comment: @Tim it's already changed.

Comment: @Default - Yes, I know - because I changed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx) method.

```
var sum = (from twh in db.MytimeMaster
 where ((twh.date >= lstsun && twh.date <= tilldate) && (twh.agentID == agentid))
 select twh.totalworkinghours).Aggregate(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0), (total, next) => total + next);
```

p.s. assume used TimeSpan for time intervals.